# Drupal: updating with Drush doesn't change update status

Tags: php, drupal, maintainability, drush

I've updated my drupal installation and drupal modules, but admin/reports/updates says that Drupal version is still 6.12.
To update drupal I ran
**- drush updatecode
- drush updatedb**
(this updated only modules and said code still needs to be updated manually).
Then I uploaded core, unzipped it, allowed to overwrite older versions and again ran
**- drush updatedb**
to enable changes.
Still, admin/reports/status shows not 6.13 version as expected, but 6.12 and says core is not secure. I even ran update.php script in the end, but still core is displayed in red as well as modules located at
admin/reports/updates.

Is using drupal shell (drush) a good practice for updates? Why is status still displayed as unupdated?

Answer (score 1):

I have followed all the steps to upgrade Drupal core from 7.22 to 7.35, from copying core files to runing update.php without any error, there are no duplicate modules, all modules are updated. Running Cron shows that I have Drupal Core 7.26 but I get the security warning

"There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates."

When I go into available updates I can see INSTALLED VERSION as 7.22 and RECOMMENDED VERSION as 7.35.

I have also tried going back to version 7.22 from backup that I took before update and then tried to upgrade to 7.23 instead of 7.35 but situation is still the same.

Comment: Mistake.
Running Cron shows that I have Drupal Core 7.35

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that drush actually changed the correct files on your system. You may find it is misconfigured.

Comment: For instance, new Views version 2.6 is present in views.info, but report status screen still shows 2.3. Still researching..

Comment: What level of caching do you have on? Admin should flush caches, but something could be preventing that, you can clear all caches on the admin/performance page

Answer (score 0):

Weird. Visitting admin/build/modules should flush the modules cache, but I would bet you have more than one copy of the modules in your site. Check ./modules, ./sites/default/modules, ./sites/all/modules and ./profile/yourprofile/modules for duplicates. (afterwards, visit admin/build/modules)